# Unexpected lack of conflict while merging

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I try to merge two branches - master (current) and UrlHandlePoint (unactive):

```
$ git merge UrlHandlerPoint
```

I suggested that it will be cause of conflict because here is an obvious difference at the code (it starts at the same line # 27):

master:

```
.27    public function actionIndex()
    {
        // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
        // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
        $about="Page content \"About\"";
        $this->render('index', array('res'=>$about));
    }
```

UrlHandlerPoint:

```
.27    public function actionIndex($alias=false)
    {
        $data=Data::getDataByAlias('o_kompanii',$alias);
        $this->render('index', array('res' => $data));
    }
```

But instead of a conflict issue git just takes the version of the master branch.
Have anybody any idea why? And/or what I understand wrong here?

Comment: Was the file *changed* in both branches after the fork?

Comment: What does the version in the common base of the two branches look like?

Comment: @Charles Bailey - Sorry about an extra question (I'm a beginner of git), do you mean that I can get after 'git merge-base A B' command?

Comment: Yes, what does the file look like at the last commit that the two branches had in common.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I can get a useful information because I used to delete an exact branch, but for sure you have an assumption about a cause. I'd glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since you don't answer comments, I'll try to go ahead and guess. ;-)

Difference is not a conflict. My guess is that the file has only been changed in the `master` branch and therefore, there's no conflicting change on the branch being merged.

Comment: Michail, I'm really confused. What it means "no conflict" if there is a difference at the same lines? What is 'conflict' then?

Comment: Conflict is when the file's been changed in BOTH branches and the changes are conflicting (different). If the file's been only changed in one branch, this change simply makes it to the merged version.

Comment: Do you mean if I'd do the same but before had made any change in the file belonging to the **master** branch there would be an issue about confilct?

Comment: Exactly. If the *changes* made to the other branch con not be cleanly applied to yours — it's a conflict. Otherwise, it's just changes.

Comment: It just demands me to made experiment on some test project. I must check it myself! Otherwise I could not sleep yet :)

Comment: That's the right attitude, hope you're back to the normal sleep soon ;-)

Comment: Yes and maybe you'll be so kind to give some link where it's pointed explicitly? It's strange because I had read much about git and it sad to think I have missed such an important issue.... :(

Comment: @srgg6701, the problem is that I *haven't* read much, so I don't know where to point. It's not really specific to git. The idea is that the development process of which revision history is a representation is a sequence of changes, often represented as patches. Of merging changes from the other branch means applying changes made in the other branch to yours. If the changes (patches) apply cleanly, then there's no conflict.

Comment: Suppose you have your branch `A` and the other branch `B` with the common base `C`. Then merging `B` into `A` essentially means applying diff from `C` to `B` on top of `A`. If it can be applied, then there's no conflict.

Comment: I've got understood everything. You are right - it's not about Git it's just about logic (it is good that not all people have the same logic. Mine for example :)) My first assumption was wrong. I thought if branches' names are different there MUST be conflict anyway. Your explanation made me to change that subject's perception. Thank you very much! :)